# Pytorch sum tensors doing an operation within each set of numbers

Tags: python, sum, pytorch, tensor

I have the following Pytorch tensor:

```
V1 = torch.tensor([[2, 4], [6, 4], [5, 3]])
```

I want to do the sum of the difference of each pair of numbers (applying absolute value), something like the code below;

```
result.sum(abs(2-4), abs(6-4), abs(5-3))
```

I can do this using a for statement:

```
total = 0
for i in range(0,vector.size(0)):
    total = total + torch.abs(vector.data[i][1] - vector.data[i][0])
```

But I want to do it without using a for.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

`torch.abs(V1[:, 1]- V1[:, 0])`

and to sum over it

`torch.sum(torch.abs(V1[:, 1]- V1[:, 0]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more general approach as in the following piece of code:

```
In [46]: torch.sum(torch.abs(V1[:, :-1] - V1[:, 1:]))
Out[46]: tensor(6)
```